# Sort dimensions in SSAS Solution Explorer

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

Is there a way to sort the Dimensions in SSAS Solution Explorer window alphabetically?

[image]

**UPDATE - No sorting options with right click on Dimensions Folder**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately you cannot change the order. It is Alphabetically sorted in the Browse and in the cube it is listed as how you add it. If Dimension B is created before A, then in the Cube tab it will be listed as B, A. please see this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2b0c830-d9cb-4106-8c07-615436d81371/dimension-sorting-in-solution-explorer-ssas)

Comment: there is no such an Option

Comment: I've added an Update to the question

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for the Answer